# Batman v Superman: Wonder Woman at Lex's Party

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the film, Bruce Wayne attends a party to attach a device to Lex's servers and steal information.  He mingles while the download progresses, then returns to find that the device has been removed.  Diana Prince sticks around long enough to make sure Bruce sees her, then leaves.

Later, Bruce tracks her down and she explains:

> She stole the data because Lex has "a photo that belongs to her", but couldn't decrypt the files, so she put the data capture device in the glove compartment of Bruce's car, to return it to him.

However, this raises a few problems:

> 1. How would stealing a digital copy of the photo get the photo out of Lex's hands?
> 2. Why would she go to Lex's party if he already knew at least some aspect of her abilities?
> 3. What was her plan for stealing the data if she didn't happen to run into a billionaire in the process of clumsily stealing it himself?

So my question is, is Wonder Woman's presence and activity at the party a plot hole, or are there clues elsewhere in the film which explain these potential inconsistencies?

Comment: I don't know if there's evidence for this in the film, but I believe she did not know there was a digital copy of the photo. I think her mission essentially failed once she realized the photo had been digitized. (and the greater purpose of her mission certainly failed with the knowledge that Lex had files on various metahumans, including herself)

Comment: It may be that she was not there to erase anything, but rather to get a copy of something that she no longer had (or never had). Meaning, she simply wanted that photo because of a sentimental value she attached to it. I bet she didn't have a copy.

Comment: @ResonantPictures that's actually a really good point.

Comment: Said Taghmaoui, the French actor of North-African origin that plays the guy at the extreme right on the picture, will be in the Wonder Woman movie. So the picture, or the people on it, will probably be important in the movie. Maybe she needed to see the picture, more than having it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't have enough info on Diana's plans or motivations, as the movie is narrated from the point of view of the other two characters in the trinity and Diana is maintained on purpose as a mystery.

She might have had different plans for that night and then changed them the moment she noticed Bruce stealing the data. Maybe even she lied to Bruce when he asked her about her motivations.

There isn't enough info on her to know exactly what her true plans are, so we cannot argue that there is a plot hole with her presence at the party.

What she would have done in case she hadn't seen Bruce is totally open to speculation.

Comment: Fair enough; I guess that's the best we can hope for until the sequel, or her standalone film.